# should js assertion is wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, should.js

I'm using should.js && mocha as test framework to build an application.

I'm returning 'true' for an API method and I found out that should.js was accepting everything as true, which is not.

I set up the following test:

```
describe('Login', function(){

    it('Should login and return true', function(done){
        isTrue().should.be.true;
        done();
    });
});

function isTrue()
{
    return 'false';
}
```

And Powershell + mocha result was :

```
PS C:\Dev\project> mocha --grep logi*


  Login
    √ Should login and return true


  1 passing (27ms)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: `return 'false';`?? Why return the **string** `'false'` (which is truthy)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to trigger the assertion:

```
 isTrue().should.be.true();
                         ^--- here
```

If we check the `should.js` [source code](https://github.com/shouldjs/should.js/blob/master/lib%2Fext%2Fbool.js#L23) we will see that the only way for the 
`should.be.true` to be fulfilled is when the `true` (a boolean) exactly is returned (which is not the same as `'true'` string).

```
  Assertion.add('true', function() {
    this.is.exactly(true);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @zerkms, that was exactly what I thougth. According should.js 'true' should not pass the assertion, but in my case it still does.  https://github.com/tj/should.js/#true

Comment: @wOvalle provide some code, we have no idea what "your case" is

Comment: The real problem is that the assertion must have with a function (), afer adding the parenthesis everything worked as usual.